# How can I measure noise-reduction after applying an autoencoder?

Tags: deep-learning, model-evaluation, autoencoders, noise

In my setting I have 21 numerical features (and ten thousands of rows) and I assume that they are noisy measurements of the real features.

In order to learn the real features I think about applying an autoencoder. I thought about adding one hidden layer with 6 hidden layers. Then I would apply 21 output layers to reconstruct the features.

The final aim is to use the features in a binary classification model.

How can I measure the noise reduction - the gain from applying the autoencoder - in this setting (besiders fitting my model and observing the accuracy)?

Answer (score 2):

Autoencoder is basically a glorified pca, and you can treat it as such. With PCA you would look at how much variance is explained by each component an same can be done with autoencoder. In that case your noise reduction equals to variance that is not captured by autoencoder.